# Removing namespace from child elements when marshelling

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I am using jaxb2.1

I am unmarsheling generated xml files object back into XML.
But I am getting extra namespaces in the child elements and I have no idea how to get rid of them:

```
<abc:buttons xmlns:abc="http://www.abc-sa.com/schema/abc1.x" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" interfaceVersion="1.0" partition="Distributor">
`<button xmlns:abc="http://www.abc-sa.com/schema/abc1.x" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#`"` identifier="UID-1d1ed99a-8ebe-4da3-88af-2917a6708470" name="doratis" type="Supplier" webAddress="" phone=""/>
<button xmlns:abc="http://www.abc-sa.com/schema/abc1.x" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" identifier="UID-ssssssss-b2bd-4346-b196-7b7b160e5840" name="doratis" type="Supplier" webAddress="" phone=""/>
</abc:buttons>
```

This is how I create an element:

```
private final static QName _Button_QNAME = new QName("http://www.abc-sa.com/schema/edx1.x", "Organization");

public JAXBElement<ButtonType> createButtonTypeElement(ButtonType buttonType) {
        return new JAXBElement<ButtonType>(_Button_QNAME, ButtonType.class, null, buttonType);
}
```

I am using getEdxNamespacePrefixMapper to set the prefix. but what Am I missing here?

Thanks,
ray.